# Tap gesture to NOT occur when touching a specific location - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have used touchesBegan to provide functionality for my UIButtons and have used a tapped gesture to provide functionality for my main player SKSpriteNode making it jump when triggered.

//Code regarding the UIButton touch

```
  override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
  //touches began is only used for GUI buttons -> not to affect player

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        //We get location of the touch
        let locationOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        if muteButton.contains(locationOfTouch) {  //mute the game  
            timer.invalidate()
            audioPlayer.volume = 0
        }
```

//Code regarding the tap

```
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.tapped(gesture:)))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

......

func tapped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {  //used to make the player jump      
            player.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 60))
            player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true */

            }
```

My problem is that when I press on the restartButton the tap gesture is also activated later when the touch ends. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using a separate tap gesture recognizer? Why not include the player jumping code inside `touchesBegan` if the user doesn't touch a button?

Comment: I am using a different tap gesture because I have also used a slide ability in which case if I use a touchesBegan it is unable to distinguish and recognise a swipe.

Comment: when you are restarting your scene, are you creating and presenting a new scene?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes

Comment: Then you are stacking gestures one after the other,  you need to remove it prior to presenting the next scene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that the two separate systems for detecting touches (using gesture recognizers and using the `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` methods) are in conflict.

One solution is to enable and disable the gesture recognizer if the touch is inside one of the buttons.

In the `touchesBegan` method, if the touch is inside a button, disable the tap gesture recognizer:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let locationOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        if muteButton.contains(locationOfTouch) { 
            // mute action
            tap.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`, re-enable the gesture recognizer:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    tap.isEnabled = true
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    tap.isEnabled = true
}
```

This way, if the touch is inside a button, the tap gesture recognizer will not fire. Whenever any touch is complete, we always re-enable the gesture recognizer in case the next touch is meant to make the player jump.

I have tested this out in an empty project, and it works.

Hopefully that helps! Good luck with your game.